# How to solve this multivariate recurrence with Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, recurrence

I would like to solve this recurrence relation:
$a_{m,n}=a_{m-1,n}+a_{m,n-1}$  with $a_{0,0}=0, a_{m,0}=1, a_{0,n}=1$
Related to the Tartaglia triangle,

the solution should be just the combinations...
$a{m,n}=Binomial(m+n,n)$

But when I try to solve it with Mathematica

```
RSolve[{a[m, n] == a[-1 + m, n] + a[m, -1 + n], a[0, 0] == 0, 
  a[m, 0] == 1, a[0, n] == 1}, a[m, n], {m, n}]
```

It just outputs the same input unevaluated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The initial condition a[m,0]=1 contradicts the initial condition a[0, 0]=0 when m=0.

Comment: perhaps the initial conditions should be at `a[1,0]` and `a[0,1]`

Comment: @AngelaRichardson I want a[m,0]=1 for all m except 0.  Anyway I've also tried with different conditions and without any.

Comment: @agentp it doesn't work either

Comment: The OEIS has a slightly difference recurrence relation that generates Tartaglia's triangle. Perhaps you could compare it with yours https://oeis.org/wiki/Pascal_triangle

Comment: @Bill A solution with Mathematica for that expression as a 2 variable relation would also be OK.

Comment: Curiously the Euler recurrence equation [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/Combinatorics/EulersNumberTriangle.nb) is also unsolved.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen do you know if Maple or other CAS software can solve them?

Answer (score 3):

maybe you know this, but you don't need `RSolve` if you just want to crunch out the numbers.

```
Clear[a];
a[0, 0] = 0; a[m_, 0] = 1; a[0, n_] = 1;
a[m_, n_] := a[-1 + m, n] + a[m, -1 + n]
Column[Table[
  Row[Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 10] & /@ 
    Table[a[i, k - i], {i, 0, k}], " "], {k, 0, 8}], Center]
```

[image]

this seems to validate your formulation, except it seems `a[0,0]` should be `1` (that doesn't make `RSolve` any happier though )

I suspect `RSolve` simply cant handle it, but you might try mathematica.stackexchange.com.

aside, if you need to use this for large numbers you probably should use memoization:

```
 a[m_, n_] := a[m,n] = a[-1 + m, n] + a[m, -1 + n]
```

for completeness the expected answer is `a[i,j]=Binomial[i+j,j]`